# C# Tasks, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel, task, currentculture

I execute code in Tasks in order to generate excel files.
But cells format are still in en-US format.
Do Tasks get the CurrentCulture parameter of the Current Thread ?

Here some code :

```
        Parallel.ForEach(_blablalist, blabla =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
            Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
            Dowork(blabla);

        }
```

Output :

fr-FR

fr-FR

This is what I want but the excel keep to be in en-US format.
Maybe Tasks have others parameters :/

Comment: probably yes, did you try to set a specific current thread culture inside the task execution? does it work?

Comment: No they don't, culture doesn't 'flow' between threads.  They will initialize to the system default.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx

Looks like that CultureInfo works only for unmanaged code :(